# Capturing FullCalendar4 click on date number event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to capture the event when the date number of a cell is clicked. I can't get  [dateClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick) to fire.

`eventClick` and `select` does not capture the event either

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
      // should work according to docs.
      dateClick: function(info) {
        console.log(info.date.toISOString());
      },
      // old api for FullCalendar3
      dayClick: function(info) {
        console.log(info.date.toISOString());
      },
      // attempt to guess the interface
      dateSelect: function(info) {
        console.log(info.date.toISOString());
      },
```

Comment: You need to read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-nav-links

Comment: got it. thanks! what is day click for then?

Comment: There's no such callback as dayClick anymore. There used to be, in version 3. In version 4 it's renamed as dateClick, which is used to detect clicks on the empty part of the day (i.e. any area not covered by events or by the day number).

Comment: oops, i meant dateClick. Alright. Thanks for helping!